# Why is entanglement the only type of quantum correlation that can exist between subsystems of pure state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

I read that if we have composite system having a pure state, then only quantum correlation its subsystems can have between them is entanglement. Why is that so?

Comment: I'm surprised that there is an another correlation type rather than entanglement.

Comment: @ChoMedit If I remember correctly, the quantum discord quantifies quantum correlations and it may be nonzero on some unentangled states. This signals more quantum correlations than just entanglement. Corrections are appreciated if this is wrong

Answer (score 1):

If a multipartite system is pure and unentangled, then by definition its wavefunction can be factorized into component wavefunctions.  In that case, local observables only operate on the individual factors, and can't be correlated.

For mixed states it isn't so simple.  For instance you can have the mixed state:

$$0.5 \lvert 00 \rangle \langle 00 \rvert + 0.5 \lvert 11 \rangle \langle 11 \rvert \, .$$

The individual terms are unentangled and uncorrelated, but the mixed state as a whole displays correlation.